# After Azure SPA redirect the application is giving -Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, azure, google-chrome, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I have Azur AD SPA - Vanilla-js. I am using MSAL2.13.1. I am able to enter the credentials but I am getting non-JS module files deprecated error when the Azure AD redirect back to application.

I have changed the application redirect UI to different pages also but I am getting same issue.

I checked on all the place for the non-JS module files deprecated error but no luck. Is there any thing else I can do.

I have already tried restarting the machine but its not working.

I am running the application using Visual Studio and index.html is the starting page.

Answer (score 0):

The error was different URL at the Azure AD and in the application.

in the Azure AD it was - https://localhost
in the Application     - http://locahost

due to https it was not able to redirect properly.